# Error when trying to specify schema for loading a CSV using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to build a schema to load the contents of a file which contains the following things-

1. movie_id, String
2. movie_name, String
3. plot, String
4. genre, an array of strings

Here is a sample-
[image]

Here is my schema definition-

```
customSchema = types.StructType(types.ArrayType(
                         types.StructField("movie_id", types.StringType(), True),
                         types.StructField("movie_name", types.StringType(), True),
                         types.StructField("plot", types.StringType(), True),
                         types.StructField('genre', 
                         types.ArrayType(types.StringType()), True),
))
```

Here is the error that I am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-290-10452c69a6ff> in <module>()
        3   types.StructField("movie_name", types.StringType(), True),
        4   types.StructField("plot", types.StringType(), True),
  ----> 5   types.StructField('genre', types.ArrayType(types.StringType()), True),
        6 ))

TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `apache-spark-sql`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StructType()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType) is a **`list`** of [StructField()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructField)s.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *  

customSchema= StructType([StructField("movie_id", IntegerType()),
                        StructField("movie_name", StringType()),
                        StructField("plot", StringType()),
                          StructField("genre", ArrayType(StringType()))])
```

If **`genre`** *string column* looks like `"['Indie', 'Drama', 'Action']"`, try this to convert to array of strings:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("genre", F.split(F.regexp_replace("genre", "\[|]| |'", ""),",")).show(truncate=False)

#+----------------------+
#|genre                 |
#+----------------------+
#|[Indie, Drama, Action]|
#+----------------------+
```